# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at first javascript line

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am getting a wired error when I deployed my site at firebase hosting.
it works well when i run the site locally but when i used firebase hosting it shows an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

at the first line of every single javascript file
here is my index file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Pipe.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="PipePair.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Ground.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ConnectionGene.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ConnectionHistory.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Node.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Population.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Species.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Genome.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#reserved-urls -->

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the site cant recognize all the javascript files but it does recognize the index html file and they are in the same folder

here is a javascript file

```
//a connection between 2 nodes

class connectionGene {
  constructor(from, to, w, inno) {
    this.fromNode = from;
    this.toNode = to;
    this.weight = w;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.innovationNo = inno; //each connection is given a innovation number to compare genomes

  }

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //changes the this.weight
  mutateWeight() {
    var rand2 = random(1);
    if (rand2 < 0.1) { //10% of the time completely change the this.weight
      this.weight = random(-1, 1);
    } else { //otherwise slightly change it
      this.weight += (randomGaussian() / 50);
      //keep this.weight between bounds
      if (this.weight > 1) {
        this.weight = 1;
      }
      if (this.weight < -1) {
        this.weight = -1;

      }
    }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //returns a copy of this connectionGene
  clone(from, to) {
    var clone = new connectionGene(from, to, this.weight, this.innovationNo);
    clone.enabled = this.enabled;

    return clone;
  }
}
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Can you post an example of what your JS files look like? What is `Species.js`?

Comment: Almost certainly one of your endpoints is returning XML or HTML when your code was hoping it would return JSON / JS. Did you check the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools and look at **every** http response?

Comment: @mjwills the response tab for every javascript file shows the index file .. not the actually javascript one

Comment: @mjwills i have no idea why .. it's in the same index and all javascript files are in the same folder so it should work